# Can DotNetCoreCLI build solution?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, dotnetcorecli

I have tried in my azure build pipeline to set a DotNetCoreCLI build task to build a solution but I just get an error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use
> because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.
> ##[error]Error: The process 'D:\WorkLib\DkDep372\Default_Win2019\1_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed
> with exit code 1

even though I specify solution like this:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/MyWebApp.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    solution: '$(solution)'
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
```

So my question is if `DotNetCoreCLI` can build a solution of it just can build projects?

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) page indicates that it can.
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) page says something about projects but not about solutions. I havn't been able to find a single example with a build with a specified solution.

Comment: "because this folder contains more than one project or solution file".

Comment: @LexLi - but I have specified the solution...  - see variables above.

Comment: No, you don't. `**/MyWebApp.sln` is not valid.

Comment: @LexLi - ok.... now I get it, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dotnet build` either expects either a projectfile, a solution file or nothing. When you give it no additional parameter then it will search the current directory for a project or solution file.

When you give it a file, you need to give the path to the file. In this case, you are giving it a minimatch pattern (**) to find the file, which doesn't work.

Try to run it in the correct directory or specify the full path to the file.

Comment: I thought the minimatch pattern was enough as a filename, but thanks for the explanation and tip I'll try that

Comment: It's interesting for the minimatch pattern works with other commands (such as VSBuild) and with dotnet build and project files (I.e. **/MyWebbApp.csproj)

Comment: VSBuild is a different tool with different parameters. dotnet can either compile a singel solution or multiple projects. VSBuild can handle mutliple solution files IIRC, seems that they didn't port that over.